# Scrolling in Datagrid

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I'm using MVVM. I bind datagrid to collection with some code:

```
<commonMVVMControls:GridControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ClientsListGrid,
                                                          Mode=TwoWay}"
```

It's DataGridControl class:

```
public class GridControl : DataGrid
{
    public GridControl()
    {
        this.DataContextChanged += new System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler(GridControl_DataContextChanged);
    }

    void GridControl_DataContextChanged(object sender, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var bindingItemsSource = new Binding("ItemsSource");
        bindingItemsSource.Source = this.DataContext;
        this.SetBinding(DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty, bindingItemsSource);

        this.RowStyle = new Style(typeof(DataGridRow));
        this.RowStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridRow.IsSelectedProperty, new Binding("IsSelected")));
    }
```

Now a snippet of code in ViewModel:

```
var selectedClient = this.ClientsListGrid.ItemsSource.Where(x => x.IsSelected);
        if (!selectedClient.Any()) 
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Resource.Resource.UpdateUserError, Resource.Resource.Warning, MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Stop,
            MessageBoxResult.OK);
            return;
        }

        var viewModel = new AddOrUpdateClientViewModel(_serviceContext, selectedClient.First());
```

**It works well. But if I scroll datagrid down or up, it stops working and IsSelected always equal false.**

Answer (score 0):

Try and see what happens if you disable virtualization. It might have something to do with that.

Comment: if I have EnableRowVirtualization set to false, then, my datagrid is down and application is not worked too =(

Comment: I'm found solution, it's set property  VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode to "Standard" value!